# Instantiate a class in another class code and get rid of include("class_name"), using namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, include, require

so i have a class here that have a function who requires another class to create an object.
I use namespace in both files, my question is can i get rid of this line here: `include("class.php");` and instantiate class using namespace?

here is the file from where i call the other class:

```
namespace namespaceName;

class classLoader{
     public function __construct() {
        //not used
     }

     public function executeFunctionOutsideTheNamespace() {
        include("class.php");
         new classExtended("badass");
    }
}
```

and the class by itself:

```
namespace namespaceName;

class classExtended extends classBase
{    
    public function __construct($action) {
        echo $action;
    }
}
```

I ask again, using Namespace there is no possibility to get rid of include() or require(), require_once() functions? to call directly new classExtended("badass"); ?

Comment: namespace != autoloading

Comment: Not if you have no autoloader, hence why your code dont work.

Comment: that's why i want to use namespace to make autoload classes

Comment: I prefer using composers autoloader, but you can accomplish the same thing with a few lines of code, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php / http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php